# Combinaison problem with exponential solutions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have the following problem which I can't find how to solve:

There is a pool with R row and T tiles by row. The problem happen in a night. During the first day, there are (R+T)/2 algae. They may be anywhere. During the night, there is proliferation: each tile which was adjacent horizontally or vertically to 2 tiles with algae before the night will have algae on the next day.

In other word, if I'm a tile, and there I count 1 every time a direct tile in contact with me has algae (max 4) Up, Down, Right, Left. If counts >= 2, next day I have algaes.

We care about the probability to have algae on the next day on every corner AND exactly Q on the borders (excluding the 4 corners).

**Solution**

So far, I have the probability for each corner:

Let A be the number of tile total (R*T).

X be the number of corner infected on first day.

P[X] = part1 * part2 / part3

Where (C is combination operator)

part1 = A-(8-X) **C** A-(8-X)
part2 = 4 **C** 4 - X
part3 = total number of case = A **C** B

Where X varies from 0 to 4.

For example, if X is 3, 3 corners infected on first day. For the other corner to be infected on second day, it must have 2 algae adjacent to it. So to infect 4 corners this way it takes 5 tiles. 8 - X.

This explains part1 which says how many possible combination do I have to place the others tiles.

part2 is how many different pattern we have for the corners. For example, with X = 3 we have one corner for which setup is different from the others. We have 4 ways to alternate the corners disposition. This is part2.

part3 is just th total, which is all the possible way to place the tiles.

**PROBLEM**

Now I need to find all the possible ways to have exactly Q infected tiles on the border (except corners), and the 4 corners infected, after first night.

I tried giving properties to tiles without success.
Made an algorithm which would take an eternity to solve...

So far I don't know what to do anymore.

Thanks